# Unable to find Postgresql data source in Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, nuget, datasource, npgsql

I am stuck in the middle of a project. I am having an issue with adding the data source in "Entity Data Model Wizard"

Navigation Path:::::

Solution Explorer : Models(Folder): Add : New Item : ADO.NET Entity Data Model : EF Designer From Database : New Connection

Now here in "New Connection" I want to connect my postgresql database using Postgresql Datasource but I have only SQL Server datasource option there, Anybody know how to deal with this ERROR..??

Note: I have added Npgsql, entityframework5.Npgsql through NuGet.

Comment: install the DDEX provider for Npgsql: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RojanskyS.NpgsqlPostgreSQLIntegration

Comment: Thank You... I have installed that before still the problem exist

Comment: also install this provider MSI: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases/latest

Comment: Thank You @magicandre1981... Should I have to uninstall something to install it..??

Comment: I install the Provider MSI as @magicandre1981 suggested. But still No EDMX generated. I checked the .tt file under .edmx file, there should be  classes automatically created for every table, But that to missing...

Comment: after I installed the MSI + VSIX I see "PostgreSQL Database" in server explorer when I try to add a data connection. on the emptry EDMX, right click and select update mode lfrom database, select the connection and which tables you want to include.

Comment: I did that, It did not show any error and does not have any diagram in the .edmx file. Also I checked the .tt file no classes are generated there too...

Comment: look in output window of VS if you see any error messages.

Comment: Thank You ... I have the postgresql data provider now. I have generated the edmx with no errors but it does not contain expected classes in .tt file.... Any clue on this @magicandre1981

Comment: post some pictures of all steps you did